# <rich:collapsiblePanel> not working

Tags: jsf, richfaces, collapsiblepanelextender

I'm working on a web app and i have a Panel where I used the tag `<rich:collapsiblePanel>`. But it isn't working, the arrows are showed on the display, but when I click it nothing happens. I've done exactly as the sample shows but its still not responding. Help me out please. This is the link to the sample I used.

http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=collapsiblePanel&skin=blueSky

and here is the line where i used the tag:

```
<rich:collapsiblePanel header="Client Search Filter" swithType="client">
```

Comment: Your attribute `swithType` is not correct. It should be `switchType="client"`

Comment: @MLavoie I tried everything that is shown on the sample provided on the link i posted above. I'm still new to all this, but isnt't the tags the only thing i need to make a panel a simple panel or a collapsible one?

Comment: @VasilLukachYeah that was a typo thanks for pointing that out though.